# Interactive maps on facebook

Tags: google-maps, facebook-graph-api, dictionary, checkin

We are a group of +/- 1200 expats living all over the world. 
We thought facebook might help us greate a interactive map on our group page.
Example, I lived in South Africa, Philippines and Guatemala. I click on these countries and if anouther person move to these countries they can join our group. Take their mouse and hover over/ or click on that country to see who lived there. They can then ask me questions about the country i Lived in. 
I know on Tripadvisor on my own facebook page i can do it but if we start a group, how can we link a interactive map to it?

Kind Regards
Randel